# Unable to get my Application to detect the Delete button

Tags: delphi

I apologize in advance for this vague question but can anyone give me a pointer to this problem?

The Delete key does not work as normal in my application. e.g. The Delete key has no effect in an editbox (i.e. it will not delete highlighted text) but Shift Delete does work.  This seems to be the case thoughout the application.  I have disabled all keypreviews and OnKey events in case they were causing it but the problem persists.

Can anyone suggest where I might look for the problem?

Running Windows 10 Delphi 10.3.3

Comment: Does this happen in a new empty application with no code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If this happens only in this particular application, it is likely that you have a `TActionList` or `TActionManager` with an action using `Delete` as its shortcut, or a simple menu item with such a shortcut.

For instance, you might have an `Edit` menu with a `Clear` item using `Delete` as its shortcut:

[image: Screenshot of an Edit menu with a Clear menu item, having Delete as its shortcut]

Then that action or menu item will respond to `Delete`, not allowing the focused control to do its own thing.

This kind of mistake is surprisingly common. For instance, in the Delphi IDE, you have an edit field above the editor, showing you the current class:

[image: Screenshot of the Delphi IDE's class edit box]

If you select this text and press Ctrl+C, you expect it to end up in the clipboard. But no! Instead, the selected text in the code editor (if any) is copied, even though the code editor didn't have keyboard focus.

Comment: @JohnBarrat: No problem, glad I could help!

Comment: Is it possible to keep the shortcut text but disable the shortcut action.  If you add the shortcut to the menu's caption it is impossible to align the text.

Comment: @JohnBarrat: I think that's possible, but I don't really remember how. Maybe you can set the menu item's caption to '`Clear'#9'Del'` (where `#9` is the tab character)? That seems to work, actually.

Comment: Note: GExperts has a tool that allows you to change the keyboard shortcuts for the entire IDE.